# Match two different post types and add to array wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have two different custom post types, **portfolio** and **project**. 
On the **single-project.php** page, I want to display content where `get_field('housetype')` in **project** matches with the taxonomy of the **portfolio**. The content comes from the **project** custom post type.

So far I've managed to get all relevant information but I cant find a way to only display the result where there's a match between the housetype and the taxonomy.

I thinking that pushing the item in an array when it's a match and then using a `foreach` loop to display the content in a table. I just don't know how to do this..

Here's my code so far:

```
       $args = array(
       'post_type' => array( 'portfolio', 'project' ));

   $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

   if( $my_query->have_posts()) {
       while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

           //Returns All Term Items for "my_taxonomy"
           $term_list_portfolio = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'portfolio_category', array("fields" => "all"));

           // Just get the category
           $category = $term_list[0]->name;

           // Get the house type
           $houseType = get_field('hustyp');

           $result = array($term_list[0]->name, get_field('hustyp'));


       endwhile;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to check with an if statement somewhere.
Something similar to this:

```
// Get the house type
       $houseType = get_field('hustyp');
       if($houseType == $term_list[0]->name){
         //Here you could save your post object
         //(that you declare before your while loop) to an array
         //or render what you want directly
         $posts[] = $post;
       }
       $result = array($term_list[0]->name, get_field('hustyp'));
```

Comment: But what will be inside the if statement to add the content to the array?

Comment: If there is a match you can add the matching post an array like I do in the code example and then do whatever you want with the posts you have.